# What are these spots on my lilac bush?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, lilac

New to the landscaping game. Planted a small lilac in my yard about a month ago and I am starting to see these spots on a majority of the leaves. Is this due to lack of water or nutrition?

[image: spots]

Comment: This looks like chemical damage at first glance.  Could you send a picture of the entire plant? How did you transport this guy from the nursery?  In the back of your truck?  Have you used any glyphosate recently or other chemicals, fertilizers?  Is this plant near your lawn?  Have you sprayed or fertilized your lawn used any herbicide via rotary spreader? Are these spots on just this side of the shrub?  My guess is this plant had spots of water and herbicide or fertilizer stuck to the water burning the leaves in those spots and down the midvein.  Just an idea until there is more info, thanks!

Comment: Looks  like septoria leaf spot, with some evidence of insufficient water,  but is there anything unusual on the underside of the leaves? Which variety of lilac is it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a disease caused by Alternaria that affects [many plant species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternaria#Species). Apply a fungicide using precisely the concentration stated on the label and [rotate the substances to avoid resistance](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r3101611.html#MANAGEMENT).